# pymssql ( python module ) unable to use temporary tables

Tags: python, pymssql

This isn't a question, so much as a pre-emptive answer.  (I have gotten lots of help from this website & wanted to give back.)

I was struggling with a large bit of SQL query that was failing when I tried to run it via python using pymssql, but would run fine when directly through MS SQL.  (E.g., in my case, I was using MS SQL Server Management Studio to run it outside of python.)

Then I finally discovered the problem:  pymssql cannot handle temporary tables.  At least not my version, which is still 1.0.1.

As proof, here is a snippet of my code, slightly altered to protect any IP issues:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host=sqlServer, user=sqlID, password=sqlPwd, \
                       database=sqlDB)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(testQuery)
```

The above code FAILS (returns no data, to be specific, and spits the error "`pymssql.OperationalError: No data available.`" if you call `cur.fetchone()` ) if I call it with `testQuery` defined as below:

```
testQuery = """
CREATE TABLE #TEST (
[sample_id] varchar (256)
,[blah] varchar (256) )
INSERT INTO #TEST
SELECT DISTINCT
        [sample_id]
        ,[blah]
FROM [myTableOI]
WHERE [Shipment Type] in ('test')

SELECT * FROM #TEST
"""
```

However, it works fine if `testQuery` is defined as below.

```
testQuery = """
SELECT DISTINCT
        [sample_id]
        ,[blah]
FROM [myTableOI]
WHERE [Shipment Type] in ('test')

"""
```

I did a Google search as well as a search within Stack Overflow, and couldn't find any information regarding the particular issue.  I also looked under the pymssql documentation and FAQ, found at  `http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/wiki/FAQ`, and did not see anything mentioning that temporary tables are not allowed.  So I thought I'd add this "question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: July 2016

The previously-accepted answer is no longer valid. The second "will NOT work" example does indeed work with pymssql 2.1.1 under Python 2.7.11 (once `conn.autocommit(1)` is replaced with `conn.autocommit(True)` to avoid "TypeError: Cannot convert int to bool").

Comment: Hi @gord-thompson , thanks for the update!  I'll leave my old answer, simply b/c it has more details, but I have now accepted yours as the official answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those who run across this question and might have similar problems, I thought I'd pass on what I'd learned since the original post.  It turns out that you CAN use temporary tables in `pymssql`, but you have to be very careful in how you handle commits.

I'll first explain by example.  The following code WILL work:

```
testQuery = """
CREATE TABLE #TEST (
[name] varchar(256)
,[age] int )

INSERT INTO #TEST
values ('Mike', 12)
,('someone else', 904)

"""

conn = pymssql.connect(host=sqlServer, user=sqlID, password=sqlPwd, \
    database=sqlDB) ## obviously setting up proper variables here...
conn.autocommit(1)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(testQuery)
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM #TEST")
tmp = cur.fetchone()
tmp
```

This will then return the first item (a subsequent fetch will return the other):

```
('Mike', 12)
```

But the following will NOT work

```
testQuery = """
CREATE TABLE #TEST (
[name] varchar(256)
,[age] int )

INSERT INTO #TEST
values ('Mike', 12)
,('someone else', 904)

SELECT * FROM #TEST

"""

conn = pymssql.connect(host=sqlServer, user=sqlID, password=sqlPwd, \
    database=sqlDB) ## obviously setting up proper variables here...
conn.autocommit(1)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(testQuery)
tmp = cur.fetchone()
tmp
```

This will fail saying "`pymssql.OperationalError: No data available.`"  The reason, as best I can tell, is that whether you have autocommit on or not, and whether you specifically make a commit yourself or not, all tables must explicitly be created AND COMMITTED before trying to read from them.

In the first case, you'll notice that there are two "`cur.execute(...)`" calls.  The first one creates the temporary table.  Upon finishing the "`cur.execute()`", since autocommit is turned on, the SQL script is committed, the temporary table is made.  Then another `cur.execute()` is called to read from that table.  In the second case, I attempt to create & read from the table "simultaneously" (at least in the mind of `pymssql`... it works fine in MS SQL Server Management Studio).  Since the table has not previously been made & committed, I cannot query into it.

Wow... that was a hassle to discover, and it will be a hassle to adjust my code (developed on MS SQL Server Management Studio at first) so that it will work within a script.  Oh well...